# Wrong error in SSIS - [Execute SQL Task] Error: There is an invalid number of result bindings returned for the ResultSetType: "ResultSetType_Rowset"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have an Execute SQL task which gives returns only one row with one column - a number. I set my result set to single row. Despite that, the task fails. Why ? How do I fix it ?

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: There is an invalid number of result bindings returned for the 
ResultSetType: "ResultSetType_Rowset".
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably, you haven't configured your resultset parametrs correctly. To configure it, click on ResultSet in the Execute SQL Task, click Add. In the 'ResultSetName' column, enter the exact name of the columnname that you are retrieving or simply give it 0. In the 'variablename', select the variable you created to map the data returned.

Comment: "enter the exact name of the columnname that you are retrieving or simply give it 0" - it wasn't working for me until I simply gave it 0 also had to use result set: Single row

Answer (score 1):

Old question (but Google still finds it :-))

If you want to use a rowset as result (usually to combine it with an ForEach-Loop)

- you have to create a variable with the type "Object" (e.g. MyResultSet)
- in the Execute SQL task the ResultSet property must be Full Rowset (is already, when you are receiving the error message above)
- on the ResultSet pane (left list entry) you have to add a single entry, set it name to 0 and its variable to the Object type variable (MyResultSet)
- in the ForEachLoop-Container you have to switch to the Collation pane (left list entry)
- there set the Enumerator property to Foreach-ADO-Enumerator
- the (now visible) ADO-ObjectSourceVariable has to be set to your Object variable (User:MyResultSet)
- Click onto the Variable assignment entry in the left pane
- create an entry for every column in the result set (and hope you did not use a select * for a 100 column table :-))

Answer (score 0):

In my case the ResultSet configured to "Full result set" when there were no results being returned. The Stored Procedure I was calling was simply deleting data. So I sat this to "None" and it worked..