# how many result test we can give a for execute sql task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, control-flow

I have an `ssis package` which have a `exectue sql` task it. I tried to modify the task by adding a `stored procedure` as sql statement. The `stored procedure` returns two result sets.

stored procedure:

```
create proc test
as
begin

select EmpID from Employee

select PersonID from person
end
```

I mapped the `result sets` to `result` set tab in the task with `parmeter name 0` `& 1` and assigned them to two `variables`.

[image]

When I run the package I got below error

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: There is an invalid number of result
>   bindings returned for the ResultSetType: "ResultSetType_Rowset".

However if i delete one `result set`  and execute `package` , it runs successfully. Is it possible to add more than one result set to execute sql task?  What I am missing here?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075140/wrong-error-in-ssis-execute-sql-task-error-there-is-an-invalid-number-of-re

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Execute SQL` task cannot access multiple result sets returned by a stored procedure.   It can only access the first result set.

The Result Set tab you are showing in your screen shot is not for assigning different result sets to object-type variables.   It is for assigning different columns to scalar variables.

If you changed your stored proc to return a single result set with two columns, then the way you have it in your screenshot would work.